# How to clear screen in iex?

Tags: elixir

In `irb` and many other interactive shells, I can do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the screen.

What's the equivalent in Elixir's `iex` ?

Comment: iex seems to respond to some other readline commands, i don't see why shouldn't it respond to `C-l`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Are you on a Mac? You could try <kbd>Command+K</kbd>. That usually works for me.

Comment: Note that this is Terminal-specific, and not part of iex.

Comment: Perfect. One extra note: Elixir v0.10.1 and ahead support a `clear` function in iex.

Comment: Anyone know a good terminal for windows where the clear() function works?

Comment: @Darragh judging from the source of `clear` in IEx see: 
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/iex/lib/iex/helpers.ex#L176
it is unavailable in windows machines.

Answer (score 39):

As José Valim said, you can call `clear` inside iex.

```
    iex> h clear/0
    * def clear()

    Clear the console screen.
```