# How Can We Clear the Screen in Iex on Windows

Tags: windows, elixir

Please how can we clear the screen in `Iex` on Windows

Documented method in Iex help does not work:

- `clear/0`   — clears the screen

[This StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019455/how-to-clear-screen-in-iex/19556335#19556335) also does not work in Windows.

Comment: Inside the Elixir/Erlang emulator shell on windows you do get the warning: ""Cannot clear the screen because ANSI escape codes are not enabled on this shell""

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff also cannot clear the screen on the Elixir -werl GUI

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've discovered it's possible, because native terminal in Windows 10 supports ANSI colors and escape sequences. The only thing is to enabled this in `iex` shell.

According to https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/io/ansi.ex#L41 this option is configurable. As a quick solution just type in your `iex` session following code:

`Application.put_env(:elixir, :ansi_enabled, true)`

In order to make it permanent, you can configure `iex` shell in `~/.iex.exs` file (https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-configuring-the-shell). Just paste following into the file:

`IEx.configure [colors: [enabled: true]]`

Comment: You may want to submit an issue on Elixir's github to make them aware that this is now supported under Windows 10.  They may want to alter the behavior.

Comment: The problem is that ANSI support in native terminal is implemented only in specific Windows 10 update, and I'm not sure it's ok to enable it by default for all Windows installations. I think, it should be up to user to enable ANSI in `iex`

Comment: I've just checked closed issues on their's github. They already have this ANSI support detection in master branch.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ANSI codes directly in `iex` on Windows with consoles that support them (like ConEmu or Windows 10 console.)

This will clear the screen in `iex`:

```
iex> IO.write "\e[H\e[J"; IEx.dont_display_result
```

Explanation:

- [`IO.write`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/IO.html#write/2) outputs to the console without a newline
- `\e[` is the prefix for ANSI [CSI codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI)
- `H` is the CSI *CUP – Cursor Position* code with no arguments, by default moves cursor to row 1, column 1
- `J` is the CSI *ED – Erase Display* code with no arguments, by default clears the screen from the current cursor position
- `IEx.dont_display_result` prevents the `:ok` result of `IO.write` from displaying after the screen is cleared

You can also clear the screen using `IO.ANSI` rather than raw escape codes:

`iex> IO.write [IO.ANSI.home, IO.ANSI.clear]; IEx.dont_display_result`

This is basically how `clear/1` is [implemented](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/iex/lib/iex/helpers.ex#L154).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can't clear it on Windows as far as I know. If there is one escape that we can output to the IO device to clear screens on Windows, I would love to know and add this functionality to Windows too. :)

Comment: there is, on a regular windows console we use CLS

Answer (score 3):

Your best option (if this is a real problem for you rather than an annoyance) is to use an alternate Windows shell that supports ANSI Escape Sequences.  See [this S O question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences) for why you can't simply use ANSI Escape sequences in a Windows Cmd Shell.  One command shell alternative that does support ANSI is [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/). Configuring ConEmu on your machine is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The linked answer suggests using ANSICON, which I think would be simpler than ConEmu. FYI, ConEmu is a terminal/console replacement, not a shell, and the windows console (conhost.exe) that it partially replaces is also not a shell. cmd.exe is a shell, but it has nothing to do with rendering the console window. Like any console program it gets a handle to the attached conhost.exe instance, and its standard handles for `StandardInput`, `StandardOutput`, and `StandardError` default to the console's input buffer and screen buffer.

Comment: @eryksun You're correct--I'm not being very precise in terms of what's a shell and what's a terminal/console.

Comment: I use `iex` in ConEmu and I still get the "ANSI escape codes are not enabled" message even though they clearly are (I have a color iex prompt.)

Comment: I also get the "ANSI escape codes are not enabled" message in console, and GitBash.

Comment: @jwfearn Are you getting that message from Iex?  Iex checks the OS so having Conemu makes no difference whatever.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci, yes that message is from `iex`. It seems on Windows, `iex` just doesn't do ANSI.  That's not a bad default since it doesn't always work. Unfortunately I haven't yet found a way to override this default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to `~/.iex.exs` in your home directory -- If the file doesn't exist, create it and add the following.

```
Application.put_env(:elixir, :ansi_enabled, true)
```

Edit: Note that you'll need a term that supports this, ConEmu, Cmder, etc..