# How do I clear an elixir shell?

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

This isn't the most insightful question, but I really want to be able to press Control-L and have the shell iex clear the screen. Any idea how to do this or if there's another elixir shell with this build in?

Comment: Kites you can type "clear"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear screen in iex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019455/how-to-clear-screen-in-iex)

Comment: You should also specify which shell /console you're discussing because that would make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`clear/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.Helpers.html#clear/0) clears the console screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `command` + `k` to clear the screen.

Comment: Tmux users with split windows may want to avoid this method as it clears the entire screen buffer.